# What are “unindexed dimensions” and why are coordinates *empty*?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm reading a NetCDF file and I'm getting `Unindexed dimensions`.  What does this mean and should I worry?  Is it related to the coordinates being `*empty*`?  Does it mean something is untidy in the source file?

```
In [33]: ds
Out[33]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                     (hirs-n17_nx: 7, hirs-n17_ny: 7, hirs-n18_nx: 7, hirs-n18_ny: 7, matchup_count: 11969)
Coordinates:
    *empty*
Unindexed dimensions:
    hirs-n17_nx, hirs-n17_ny, hirs-n18_nx, hirs-n18_ny, matchup_count
Data variables:
(...)
    hirs-n18_counts_ch12        (matchup_count, hirs-n18_ny, hirs-n18_nx) float64 -2.147e+09 ...
(...)

In [35]: ds["hirs-n17_radiance_ch12"]
Out[35]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'hirs-n17_radiance_ch12' (matchup_count: 11969, hirs-n17_ny: 7, hirs-n17_nx: 7)>
[586481 values with dtype=float64]
Unindexed dimensions:
    matchup_count, hirs-n17_ny, hirs-n17_nx
Attributes:
    units: mW m^-2 sr^-1 cm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unindexed dimensions" is simply dimensions that don't have an associated coordinate variable. A better section title might be "Dimensions without coordinates". There's nothing inherently wrong with this: sometimes there aren't meaningful coordinates values for a dimension, and xarray handles this just fine.

This is a new section in the `repr` for xarray objects. As of v0.9.0, [coordinates for dimensions are now *optional*](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/whats-new.html#v0-9-0-25-january-2017) in the xarray data model, rather than being filled-in with default values of the form `[0, 1, 2, ..., N-1]`.

Old behavior/repr (xarray v0.8.2):

```
>>> ds = xarray.Dataset({'foo': (('x',), [1, 2, 3])})
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
Data variables:
    foo      (x) int64 1 2 3
>>> 'x' in ds.coords
True
```

New behavior/repr (xarray v0.9.0):

```
>>> ds = xarray.Dataset({'foo': (('x',), [1, 2, 3])})
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 3)
Coordinates:
    *empty*
Unindexed dimensions:
    x
Data variables:
    foo      (x) int64 1 2 3
>>> 'x' in ds.coords
False
```

I'm glad you raised this concern. We've been tweaking th `repr` recently (see https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1199) to try to convey this new aspect of the data model in the clearest possible way, but we may not have gotten it right yet. Suggestions for improvement would be very welcome (please comment on the linked GitHub issue).

Comment: I see.  I'm still learning on how the index/coordinates system maps to the NetCDF model.